# PHP script to create private key & public address

Tags: development, address

Does anyone have an PHP code that can do what is done on this website:

https://www.bitaddress.org

Namely create private keys and associated public addresses?

Comment: For Python: http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=84238

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy using this package :

[Uniform Server Key Generator](http://wiki.uniformserver.com/index.php/SSL_PHP_Server_Key_and_Certificate_generation)

And with it running, you can just execute : `openssl_pkey_new();` to generate a private/public key set.